# PHP, MySQL and PDO - results from database missing apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am pulling out my hair so hope someone can help.

I have changed my Query function from mysql to mysqli to PDO and still cannot get the results to display apostrophes - I can see them in the database field so know they are there.

I am using a class and a function within where I feed the query for another page:

My query:

```
SELECT sum(quantity) as Total, sum(earnings) as Revenue, title 
from `sales` 
WHERE name = 'john smith' 
AND paid = 'y' 
AND earnings >0 
GROUP BY title
```

My function:

```
   $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $db_host .";dbname=" . $db_database . ";charset=UTF-8",$db_user,$db_password,array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

               $SQL = $query; 
               $stmt = $db->prepare($SQL);             
               $stmt->execute();

            $stmt = $db->query($SQL);

            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            {
                    $result_array[] = $row;                      

            }  

            $db = null;

        return $result_array;
```

The data is being pulled from the database without problem, except the apostrophe is missing where it should be.  This causes me problems as I later use this data to search another table and it fails to match.

I really hope someone can help me before I go totally bald.

All help gratefully received, please be kind :D

Comment: what apostrophe? title field?

Comment: Hi Marc - yes the title field always displays with a space where the apostrophe should be.

Comment: so start looking where it's disappearing. e.g. `var_dump($row)` inside your loop, then wherever this `$result_array` is being used. there's NOTHING in the above code that'd remove characters, so we can't help you.

Comment: When I hover over the results as they are being collected by $result_array I can see it has gone so its deffo within this function and this query.  Am I going to need a wig?

Comment: ooops - DOH!  Thanks for trying to help me Marc - I now realise I am beyond it as Ive been looking at the wrong table - Sales is missing the apostrophe :S

Answer (score 2):

In your current code your actually querying the database twice, there is also `PDO::fetchAll` which will return exactly what your trying do with the loop. Plus for better code initialize your PDO connection outside of your functions and use the global keyword to get scope of `$db` within the function or pass `$db` to the function as an argument.

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $db_host .";dbname=".$db_database, $db_user, $db_password,
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    )
);

function select_sales($name='', $paid='y'){
    global $db;

    $query = "SELECT sum(quantity) as Total,
                 sum(earnings) as Revenue, 
                 title 
              FROM `sales` 
              WHERE `name` = :name AND paid = :paid AND earnings >0 
              GROUP BY `title`";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':paid', $paid);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
?>
```

Comment: You still need to pass `$db_database, $db_user, $db_password` as argument of `yada()`

Comment: @meda your right I forgot that bit lol, not generally used to initializing PDO within a function ekk ;p

Comment: yeah its a little weird, if anything its cleaner to pass the connection itself ;)

Comment: meda - what do you mean pass the connection itself please?